# Backbone template error (not reading the template)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm learning [Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/) By Addy Osmani and im stuck into the templates part.

Here is my template:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= completed ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <label><%= title %></label>
    <button class="destroy"></button>
    </div>
    <input class="edit" value="<%= title %>">
    </script>
```

Here is my backbone view:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'todo_list',
        todoTpl: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
        events:{
            'dblclick label': 'edit',
            'keypress .edit':'updateOnEnter',
            'blur .edit':'closed'
            },
        render: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'edit','upadateOnEnter','close');
            this.$el.html(this.todoTpl(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.input = this.$('.edit');
            return this;
            },
        edit: function(){},
        updateOnEnter: function(){},
        closed: function(e){}
        });

        var todoView = new TodoView();
        console.log(todoView.el);
```

Im not sure what to expect the result but i was expecting the HTML's inside the template of id item-template but i get only

```
<li class="todo_list"></li>
```

I think im wrong somewhere, i just couldnt figure it out.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone creates `this.el` automatically when the view is instantiated, but you need to call `.render()` to run the template and place it's results inside of the element.

```
var todoView = new TodoView();
todoView.render();
console.log(todoView.el);
```

Update:

Also, your render function has a typo in it. You have `upadateOnEnter` when you should have `updateOnEnter`, and `close` should be `closed`.

```
_.bindAll(this, 'edit','updateOnEnter','closed');
```

Comment: thx loganfsmyth,
but it doesnt show anything in console log not even <li> tag. Do you need any other information? I can provide you. however i get this error => TypeError: n is undefined (in underscore.js)

Comment: i get this error => TypeError: n is undefined (in underscore.js)

Comment: @Geniusintrouble Use the unminified version of Underscore so you get useful errors. Your backbone View is defined below the template in your page, right?

Comment: i get this error on unminified version:

  TypeError: func is undefined
    ...ind === nativeBind && nativeBind) return nativeBind.apply(func, slice.call(argum...

and yes my template is above the view.

Comment: i did the typo correction... still same problem.. did you view my last error? the error is shown in underscore.js file..

Comment: thnk your help.. i had some typo again.. :p